# Tomcat выдает ошибку 404 после стартовой страницы. Тот же код без проблем работает в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, servlet, tomcat, http-status-code-404

Сделал веб проект в IDEA запускаю на Tomcat все работает никаких проблем. Сделал war файл запустил Tomcat  на удаленном компьютере задеплоил в Tomcat. Запускается, открывает стартовую страницу а дальше выдает ошибку:

> 404 "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

видимо проблема в этой части кода. Но какая проблема не могу понять.

```xml
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ProjectX.web.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ls</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это окно ошибки. Сначала подумал что проблема в версии Томката поэтому проверил на разных версиях. Ошибка такая же.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
До нажатия кнопки входа в консоли пишет ошибку 500.

Comment: Вы должны после каждого изменения в web.xml перезагружать сервер.Вы перезагружали?

Comment: Если вы сделали то и не работает - покажите url

Comment: а почему вы решили что именно здесь проблема?

Comment: Не надо писать "solved" в заголовок. Лучше поставьте галочку на свой ответ и все.

Comment: Откройте вкладку network, перезагрузите страницу, и посмотрите, какой именно ресурс не найден. Также проверьте логи Tomcat, стартовало ли ваше приложение, нет ли ошибок на старте

Answer (score 0):

Где-то потерялся контекст приложения, так как возвращает адрес по которому может быть другое приложение. Контекст приложения можно получить/посмотреть так `request.getContextPath()`.

Comment: через /ls у меня идет логин сервлет проверяет пароль если соотвествует то перебрасывает в index.jsp. Почему-то после проверки не находит index.jsp. Хотя он в  war файле присутствует проверял. Пересобираение  war-а может помочь?

Answer (score 0):

Целую неделю экспериментировал с разными версиями Tomcat-a, попробовал TomEE, jBoss, Jetty все напрасно... каждый из этих серверов работал с проблемами с первого раза вообще ни один не запустился(через IDEA). В конце концов понял что проблема в самой InteliJ IDEA Ultimate(version 2018.2 updated to 2018.3). Откатился на 2016.3 все заработало как надо без ошибок и даже по шустрее.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно порт `8080` в который вы стучитесь просто закрыт.

Comment: Думаю, это не тот случай, так как тогда браузер бы показал, что страница недоступна. А тут сервер tomcat выдаёт 404, то есть сервер работает, отвечает на запросы, поэтому с портом должно быть всё в порядке.