# 404 - не найдено в tomcat

Tags: java, servlet, tomcat

На запрос любой из страниц проекта tomcat выдает [image: собственно вот эту ошибку]

Доходит до идиотизма, создал в проекте специально сервлет и jsp под него, которые не блочатся фильтрами и ни с чем не взаимодействуют, все равно та же история.
Замучался второй день понимать что и как.

Собственно код jsp

```
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: proto_000
  Date: 04.02.2020
  Time: 19:04
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>BASE PAGE HEAD</title>
</head>
</html>`
```

И код самого сервлета

```
@WebServlet(
    name = "BaseServlet",
    description = "Login user or admin servlet",
    urlPatterns = {"/home"}
)
public class BaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("basePage1.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

pom файл, если нужен

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>ServletFilter_2</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.13</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/standard -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Прошу помочь, уже все мозги себе взорвал.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/952407/204920

Answer (score 0):

Run -> Edit Configuration

Далее перейдите в вашу конфигурацию tomcat

-> Deployment

Внизу поле Application сontext необходимо полностью очистить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]